# Instagram top media api "distributed" searching for many users database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture, instagram-api, system-design

I'm currently in the process of trying to collate stats for the top media in instagram for different hashtags. For what it's worth my stack will be nodejs with a mysql database, but it's really only the database structure I'm asking about here. Of course if people can see a better way of doing this then please say.

Looking at the Instagram api docs ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/recently_searched_hashtags ), a user access token can only search 30 unique hashtags in a rolling 7 day period.

There are several tools out there that search hashtags and seem to do this for more than 30 hashtags per user (one of which is even listed as a case study https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/success-stories/ ). I'm trying to figure out a way to do this myself whilst only using the official APIs. My current solution is based on the following assumptions:

1. For every user, I can use their access_token to query 30 unique hashtags from the Instagram API (not necessarily the hashtags they're interested in)
2. There can possibly be duplicate hashtags to search across users, therefore I don't need to search the same hashtag twice.

Now in figuring out how to do this, I would do the following.

1. Query each user via the Instagram API to get their latest media and extract the hashtags from them.
2. Store each unique hashtag in a database table called `hashtags`. I want to search these values later.
3. Store a relation between each media item and the relevant hashtag_id in `media_to_hashtag`.
4. Store the users access_token in a database table (`access_token`) with an "available" count of how many hashtags it can search.

   ```
   table hashtag
      id int PK AI
      hashtag varchar(100)
      igid unsigned bigint (Instagram ID)
      access_token text
      last_searched timestamp

   table media_to_hashtag
       media_id bigint PK,
       hashtag_id int PK
       stats....

   table access_token
      access_token_id INT AI PK,
      token text,
      usage int default 30,
      user_id unsigned bigint. (in case we need to invalidate/delete a user)
   ```

On a separate daily or twice daily "job" I can then

1. Query all hashtags that don't currently have an access_token assigned to them and take one from the access_token table with a usage greater than 0 and decrease the `usage`.
2. Query Instagram for all the hashtags and update any stats on the `media_to_hashtag` table

Does this fill like a viable solution?

The bit I'm struggling with is whether this is a viable way to do the access token mapping, or if it could be improved somehow, bearing in mind the need to update access tokens and potentially remove them. Would I be better with another mapping table e.g

```
hashtag_to_access_token
 hashtag_id int PK,
 access_token_id int PK
```

That way I only store the access token in one table which would help in update scenarios. I'm not sure if there's anyway I can use a constraint to ensure an access token is only used 30 times in this way.

This is quite long winded, but I was trying to provide as much info as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "use their access_token" -- yet that column is in the table `hashtag`.  Sounds wrong.  I see `access_token_id` that is not used.  Let's see some of the `SELECTs` you will be needing.

Comment: That's in relation to the Instagram API to begin with, so that I can then populate my hashtag table. I can get their access token from the API, but then I will store it to make subsequent calls